# Copy/paste greeting by user inputted name. (HTML & JS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, clipboard

I'm trying to create a copy paste sheet, which will first ask for a user input(their first name).

Once the name is submitted, it will ideally be used within the copy to clipboard button as seen in the HTML/JS below.

Ultimately I'm hoping that the entire greeting with the inputted name can be easily copy and pasted.

e.g.

Hi there, #name .

Currently the user input is working but I'm struggling to have this replicated to the clipboard text area with the user's name.

https://codepen.io/dmcp123/pen/gOBYQRb

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var greeting = function(name) {
            var name = $('#enterName').val();
            name = 'Hi there,' + ' ' + name;
            console.log('Hi there,' + '' + name);
            $('#result').text(name);
        };

    $('#submit_this').click(function() {
        greeting();
        //prompt('Hi there,' + '' + name);
    });
})

let copyText = document.querySelector(".copy-text");
copyText.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  let input = copyText.querySelector("input.text");
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  copyText.classList.add("active");
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  setTimeout(function () {
    copyText.classList.remove("active");
  }, 2500);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    background: #F7EDE2;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.label {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #111;
}
.copy-text {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
}
.copy-text input.text {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.copy-text button {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #5784f5;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.copy-text button:active {
    background: #809ce2;
}
.copy-text button:before {
    content: "Copied";
    position: absolute;
    top: -45px;
    right: 0px;
    background: #5c81dc;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: none;
}
.copy-text button:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: 25px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #5c81dc;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: none;
}
.copy-text.active button:before,
.copy-text.active button:after {
    display: block;
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #5784f5;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
footer p {
    margin: revert;
    padding: revert;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form>
    <div>Your name:</div>
    <input name="enterName" id="enterName" type="text">
    <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="submit">
        <input value="submit" id="submit_this" type="button">
    </div>
</form>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="copy-text">
    <input type="document" class="text" value="(Hi there,  " + name>
    <button><i class="fa fa-clone"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm struggling to have this replicated to the clipboard button/text area with the user's name.

Comment: You must be more specific, please update your question wiht the desired output.

Comment: `value="(Hi there,  " + name>`Not sure what you expect that to be doing in the HTML

Comment: You are selecting the textbox, but you are setting the text the user added to the "result" div. So why are you not setting the input's vaue?

Comment: Okay, so I have since updated the code so that the result(greeting + first name) is within the text area, however I can't seem to get the button to display so the outputted text can be copied to clipboard.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dmcp123/pen/gOBYQRb

Comment: Ideally this is what I would like to display: https://ibb.co/xqZ48jp